# Not able to read resource files from src/test/resources in STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resources, sts

I created folder `src/test/resources/` in root project directory, and inside this I added a file in folder **jsons** as `jsons/server_request.json`.

Now I am trying to read this file by calling a the static function in CommonTestUtilityclass given as:

```
public class CommonTestUtility {
    
    public static String getFileAsString(String fileName) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }
}
```

Now while calling this function as

```
class ServerTest {
@Test
void test_loadResource() {
    String content = CommonTestUtility.getFileAsString("jsons/server_request.json");
}

}
```

, It's giving me the error as:

```
CommonTestUtility - Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null.
```

> I tried to include the `src/test/resources/` in the run configuration
> of Junit ServerTest.java, but still it's not able to find out the
> resource
> How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the same scenario you describe and your code works for me.
Could you double-check that your project looks like mine below? If so, I suspect it might be something with your environment.

[image: My Project]

Comment: Yes, that what I have, but I am using STS 4 , maybe I skipped some step, Could you explain what all steps you've done after creating resources folder manually ?

Comment: I can do better than that, can show you exactly what I did:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnymUn6gT7Q

Comment: Let me know if it still doesn't work after following the video, in that case we can have a call tomorrow and solve it together 

Comment: @GiuseppeValierio. Yeah, I tried again, and It worked.

Answer (score 3):

https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

This above link might be helpful.
The getResource() method return an URI you need to change
.getFile() function to. toURI().
Simple code

private File getFileFromResource(String fileName) throws URISyntaxException{

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
    if (resource == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found! " + fileName);
    } else {

        // failed if files have whitespaces or special characters
        //return new File(resource.getFile());

        return new File(resource.toURI());
    }

}
```

Comment: I did same thing just used a static method to get a resource else everything is similar, still  facing issue.

Comment: try your luck with classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName).Please look on the  article it has given the method to read the file from Test unit resource folder